# Need to interface python and Matlab

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, anaconda

I need to run a complex Python script into a Matlab program.
I already tried to use the built-in support (with pyversion and py.importlib) but it struggle with importing libraries such as numpy.
Here's an example of the error:
for python (*script called hello.py*)

```
import numpy
def world():
    return('hello world!')
```

To import the script to matlab I use the following command:

```
path='C:\XXXX\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe';
pyversion(path)
py.importlib.import_module('hello')
py.hello.world()
```

if we run the script like that we get an error with numpy:
[Complete matlab error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd6PW.png)

but, if we remove the import statement it works fine:
[Without numpy import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfBch.png)

Do you have suggestions for me?
PS: I checked the path used in pyversion: it's the same that Anaconda is currently using

Comment: Please provide more details. Which matlab version are you using? This says it has to be 2014b or later: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-run-Python-in-MATLAB

Comment: I'm currently using r2016b. 
For the reccord the build in support works as long as I'm not trying to import any module from python(numpy, pandas, so on...)

Comment: how are you trying to import those modules?

Comment: I'm importing my script using importlib and import module.  
for the libraries, it's in the script with a import.

Comment: Can you show us your code exactly?

Comment: Matlab and python?

Comment: Both. I suggest you edit the question than more people can answer it

Comment: also suggest to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Do you get the same error if you import Numpy directly from the script, not through “fonction”? If yes, remove that import from your MCVE, as we can’t execute it this way. If not, show what happens inside that one before it imports Numpy. Please read [mcve].

Comment: if I try to import numpy from the script the results is the same. I'll change my example for something simpler